# How to draw confusion matrix on Matlab if given data type is string?

Tags: matlab, classification

I have 2 arrays where one of them shows true class of examples  the  other shows predicted ones. Their size is Nx1. They are written as string. I can compute the confusion matrix with confusionmat function but when I try the plotconfusion function it gives error :

```
Error using plotconfusion>standard_args (line 246)
Value{1,1} is not numeric or logical.

Error in plotconfusion (line 102)
    update_args = standard_args(args{:});

Error in knnex (line 193)
plotconfusion(testclass,label);
```

I  don't want to change strings to numbers so is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you not want to change the strings to numbers?

Comment: I wanted to make it easy to understand. I changed it to numbers now but it takes too long to calculate still waiting matlab to finish calculation for a while. confusionmat took much shorter calculation time.

Comment: I don't understand that statement.  Why would changing it to numbers make it too long to calculate?  Where is your relevant code or issue that illustrates this problem?

Comment: The first problem was showing class names on graph. I just wanted to make graph more clear. The new problem is instead of number-string issue, the  plotconfusion takes much longer time compared to confusionmat.

Comment: I solved both problems using mirlab toolbox. Which allows me put on class names and executes much faster. http://mirlab.org/jang/matlab/toolbox/machineLearning/help/confMatPlot_help.html